# Select2 how to add values before ajax call

Tags: javascript, default

I have next select2:

```
siteSelector = $('#siteSelector').select2(
{
   placeholder : "Select site ...",
   ajax : {
      type : 'GET',
      dataType : 'json',
      contentType : 'application/json',
      url : {url_of_my_rest_service},
      data : function(term, page) {
         return {
            startswith : term,
         };
      },
      results : function(data, page) {
         var items = data.content;
         var res = {
            results : []
         }, i;
         for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
         res.results.push({
            id : items[i].id,
            text : items[i].name
         });
      }
      return res;
   }
},
minimumInputLength : 3
});
```

How can I make that when I press a dropdown button some values will already be preloaded in there?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to insert the data in the DOM before calling the ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//as many as you need, using loop or manually
$('#siteSelector').append("<option value='value1'>Value 1</option>")
//only then start select2 using the function you wrote
//siteSelector = $('#siteSelector').select2(......
})
```

As far as I know, the data attribute in select2 doesn't work well (or at all) with ajax calls. This method will work.